# Get MySQL results from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `users` and `logins` (timestamps on login_time column)

I'm trying to look inside the users table to find users that haven't logged in more than 50 minutes.

Some users have never logged in, meaning they have no entries in the logins table as yet, but I need to be able to find them too in the query result, because they haven't login.

This is what I have, but so far I can only see the users with login entries in the "logins" table, for more than 50 minutes, but any other user that never logged in is not showing up.

```
    mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM users l 
    LEFT JOIN logins h 
    ON l.id = h.user_id 
    WHERE abs(timestampdiff(MINUTE,now(), h.`login_time`)) >'50' 
    ")
```

If I remove the WHERE timestampdiff I can see them all of course, but showing NULL value in the login_time column.

How can I also show those other users in the result too?

Thanks.

Comment: You can set default timestamp to -infinity, if user has never logged in

Comment: Add an `OR h.user_id IS NULL` on the WHERE clause...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get users who have never logged in just add `OR h.user_id IS NULL`

```
SELECT *
FROM users l 
LEFT JOIN logins h 
ON l.id = h.user_id 
WHERE abs(timestampdiff(MINUTE,now(), h.`login_time`)) >'50'
     OR h.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

two possible solutions:

The first one: Add an `is null` condition to your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    users l 
LEFT JOIN 
    logins h ON l.id = h.user_id 
WHERE 
    abs(timestampdiff(MINUTE,now(), h.`login_time`)) >'50' 
    OR h.login_time is null;
```

The second one: Use the `coalesce` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    users l 
LEFT JOIN 
    logins h ON l.id = h.user_id 
WHERE 
    coalesce(abs(timestampdiff(MINUTE,now(), h.`login_time`)), 60) >'50'
```

`coalesce()` will return the first non null argument.

Comment: probably need to use 51 instead of 50 in the coalesce

Comment: @DavidFleeman True! Sorry for the typo (meant to write 60)... correcting

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help!